# multiple show hide toggle with div sliding out

Tags: javascript, show-hide, jquery

I am new to coding and need help with jQuery. I have 2 `<div>`s (one with an image, the other with a menu list, both 50% width) and I need to be able to click one of the menu options to make a new div (50% width) appear from the right while reducing the other 2 divs width to 25% each. Then clicking on the same menu option to hide the new div and revert back to the original widths. But if I click on another menu option while the new div is visible, I need it to change the content to that specific menu option content.

How can I swap the left-hand `<div>` out with jQuery?

Here's the HTML I'm working with:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
     <!-- SCRIPT FILES -->    
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>     
     <!-- CSS STYLESHEETS -->    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">    
        <div id="header">        
        </div><!--header-->        
            <div id="container">        
                <div class="box-container">                
                    <div class="box1">                    
                        <img src="images/Untitled-1.png" alt="logo">                    
                    </div>                    
                    <div class="box2">                    
                        <div id="nav">                        
                            <ul>                            
                                <li><a>hello!</a></li>                                
                                <li><a>ADVERTISING</a></li>                                
                                <li><a>DESIGN</a></li>                                
                                <li><a>ABOUT</a></li>                                
                                <li><a>BLOG</a></li>                                
                                <li><a>SHOP</a></li>                                
                            </ul>                            
                        </div><!--nav-->                        
                    </div><!--box2-->                    
                    <div class="box3">                    
                        <div id="ADVERTISING" class="content">ADVERTISING</div>                        
                        <div id="DESIGN" class="content">DESIGN</div>                        
                        <div id="ABOUT" class="content">ABOUT</div>                        
                        <div id="BLOG" class="content">BLOG</div>        
                        <div id="SHOP" class="content">SHOP</div>                    
                    </div>                    
                </div><!--box-container-->            
            </div><!--container-->        
        <div id="footer">        
        </div><!--footer-->        
    </div><!-- wrapper-->        
</body>
</html>​
```

Here's a working jsFiddle with the styles: http://jsfiddle.net/YcphY/6/

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YcphY/5/ i've tried copying and pasting lots of other examples from here, but im at a loss.

Comment: Your JSFiddle won't work because you're trying to load assets with relative URLs even though they are on the wrong domain. To really harness the usefullness of JSFiddle, you should split-out the HTML/JS/CSS into their separate panels.

Comment: you can do it without js btw

Comment: thanks guys, im still lost on this, and nick your comments with the examples seemed to have disappeared for some reason.

Comment: How do you do it without js? is it css3 animations?

Comment: i messed that you want to toggle show/hide i mean :active

Answer (score 1):

For starters, [here's a method that ties the below examples of how to do this into the animation you're after](http://jsfiddle.net/YcphY/13/):

```
$(function() {
  $("#nav").delegate("li","click", function() {
    var newDiv = $(".box3 .content").eq($(this).index()-1);
    newDiv.siblings().hide().end(); // hide the others
    if(newDiv.is(":visible")) {
      // if shown, fade it out, when the fade finishes, slide everything back
      newDiv.fadeOut(function() { 
        $(".box3").hide(); 
        $(".box1, .box2").animate({ width: "50%" });
      });
    } else {
      // if not shown, then slide over space, then fade in
      $(".box1, .box2").animate({ width: "25%" }, function() {
        $(".box3").show();
        newDiv.fadeIn("fast");
      });
    }
  });        
});​
```

Given your current CSS you can do this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#nav").delegate("li a","click", function() {
        $(".box3").show();
        $("#" + $(this).text()).show().siblings().hide();
    });        
});​
```

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/YcphY/7/), though you can see the CSS will need a bit of work to get it going 100%.  I suggest a few changes though: give your links and containers matching IDs, like this:

```
<li><a id="ad">ADVERTISING</a></li> 

<div id="ad-container" class="content">ADVERTISING</div>
```

Then the JS can be:

```
$(function() {
    $("#nav").delegate("li a","click", function() {
        $(".box3").show();
        $("#" + this.id + "-container").show().siblings().hide();
    });        
});
```

[Here's a working example of that](http://jsfiddle.net/YcphY/10/)...it allows you to change the text at will and not worry about the JS breaking later.  Another alternative yet is to go off the index of the link in the list using [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) of the `<li>`, if the number of links was consistent with the `<div>`s in all cases, even if there's an offset because of the "hello!" link.

[Here's an example of an index approach](http://jsfiddle.net/YcphY/11/) with your current HTML:

```
$(function() {
    $("#nav").delegate("li","click", function() {
        $(".box3").show();
        $(".box3 .content").hide().eq($(this).index()-1).show();
    });        
});​
```

Comment: I copied all the code from the top jsfiddle into my files, but it doesn't seem to work. Am i missing something to do?

Comment: Do I need to do a document.ready thing at the start of my js file?

Answer (score 1):

I think jQuery's [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function might be of use to you.

What you'd need to do is either have a hidden div positioned out of the window added to your HTML (or maybe add it dynamically using jquery on `document.ready` event, if you prefer) and the use the above mentioned animate function to slide it in and out and bind it to the menu item's click function.

## Sample Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slide').click(function(){
    var hidden = $('.hidden');
    if (hidden.hasClass('visible')){
        hidden.animate({"left":"-1000px"}, "slow");
        hidden.removeClass('visible');
    } else {
        hidden.animate({"left":"0px"}, "slow");
        hidden.addClass('visible');
    }
    });
});​
```

## Explanation

In the above code we are binding code to the `click` event of an element with a `id` "slide". Once the element is clicked the code gets initiated. We check if the `.hidden` has a css class called "visible". If not we animate the hidden div to slide in. and if it has a visible class then slide it out.

## Working Fiddle

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QPhB3/) for you

## Some pointers

- In the hidden div's CSS remember to specify a z-index greater than that of the current left panel.
- In the hidden div's CSS remember to set `position` to `absolute` and `left` to around `-1200px` (or greater than window.width() to make it work on all screen sizes.)

Comment: you are welcome, i have updated the answer and added a few more pointers.

Comment: guys can you help me with the other answer please? i cant get it to work in my browser.

Comment: other answer is overcomplex

Comment: I dont know how to incorporate this answer into my code. Im a real amateur here.

Comment: i need it to come in from the right instead, and also to toggle the width of box 1 and box 2 to 25% each on toggle.